# Is there any difference between Tetanus and Tetany?

Tags: health

Both the tetanus and tetany are related to muscle spasms and the latter is due to lack of calcium but is any collaboration between them regarding *Clostridium tetani*. also?

Comment: Did you do any research on this, and can you share what you found?

Comment: @anongoodnurse I want to know if this statement is correct if we say the other way: Tetany is rapid spasm in muscles caused by *Clostridium tetani*?

Comment: Again, did you do any research on this, and can you share what you found?

Comment: @anongoodnurse I am asking, not saying !